# Rewrite all subdomain data to a new domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a video on my site with from vimeo using

I would like to write:

I can not find an .htaccess rewrite code to convert player.mydomain.com to player.vimeo.com Nothing actually works.  Maybe it not possible?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, try this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^player.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://player.vimeo.com/$1 [R=permanent]
```

That will simply throw the filename and query-string requested to player.vimeo.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try add new DNS canonical record, like:

```
 oldsubdomain   CNAME       newsubdomain.domain.com.
```

In your domains:

```
player CNAME player.vimeo.com.
```